# Dúvidas Matrizes Python

Tags: python, lista, matriz

Estou tentando criar uma função que retorna a matriz "menor complementar" de uma matriz qualquer. Isso é, dada uma matriz por exemplo:

```
mat=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

A menor complementar associada ao elemento da posição `[0][0]` seria a matriz com a linha e a coluna do elemento `[0][0]` eliminada, ficando `[[5,6],[8,9]]`.

Minha função é a seguinte:

```
def menor_complementar(M,L,C):
    #Onde: M é a matriz principal, L é o número da linha do elemento associado e C o número da coluna do elemento associado
    matriz_resultado=M[:]
    del(matriz_resultado[L])
    for linha in matriz_resultado:
        del(linha[C])
    return matriz_resultado
```

Quando eu executo:

```
menor_complementar(mat,0,0)
```

O output que obtenho é exatamente o que eu espero: (`[[5,6],[8,9]]`)

Porém quando eu tento chamar esta função de novo ocorre algo inesperado.
Por exemplo, se eu a chamar agora com os seguinte parâmetros:

```
menor_complementar(mat,1,1)
```

A saída é `[[1, 3], [8]]` ao invés de `[[1,3],[7,9]]` como deveria.

Alguém saberia como arrumo isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que Python não tem tipos nativos de "matriz" - em geral, em programas pequenos, as pessoas inventam um tipo de matriz - e programas que  vão fazer mutias coisas com matrizes, podem usar a biblioteca NumPy, que sim, tem um tipo de matriz que tem dezenas de operações específicas possíveis, é bastante otimizado, e etc...

E, principalmente para quem está começando em programação, ou em Python, uma forma bem comum de representar uma matriz é como uma "lista de listas", em que cada lista interna representa uma linha da matriz. A partir do seu código, podemos ver que essa foi sua abordagem.

Então, o seu problema está em que quando temos um objeto composto em Python, se criamos uma outra referência pra ele, as duas referências são para o mesmo objeto. Você evita isso com sua matriz em si - a lista de listas, ao escrever a linha `matriz_resultado=M[:]` - essa é uma expressão em Python que cria uma "fatia do começo até o final de uma sequência", e portanto faz uma cópia de uma lista. Alterações nessa cópia não são refletidas na matriz original.

**No entanto, você não faz cópias de cada linha da sua matriz**: ou seja, o objeto `list` que é a linha 0 da sua matriz `matriz_resultado` é o *mesmo* objeto `list` que é a linha 0 da sua matriz `M`.

Então, se você chamar a sua função com uma matriz de teste "M1",  o resultado vai ser correto, mas **cada linha da matriz original "M1" vai ser alterada *também***, quando as linhas da `matriz_resultado` forem alteradas dentro da função.   (E a linha que foi removida da `matriz_resultado` por inteiro não é afetada, claro).

Um simples "print" entre as chamadas a sua função podem deixar a coisa bem clara. No modo interativo colei exatamente o seu código acima, e chamei a sua função:

```
In [6]: a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]                                                                                  

In [7]: a                                                                                                                      
Out[7]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [8]: menor_complementar(a, 0, 0)                                                                                            
Out[8]: [[5, 6], [8, 9]]

In [9]: a                                                                                                                      
Out[9]: [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

## Como resolver:

Isso se resolve garantindo-se que todos os sub-elementos do seu objeto composto, no caso, as linhas da matriz, também sejam copiados quando se faz uma cópia da matriz que será modificada.

Isso poderia ser feito manualmente com um `for`:

```
def menor_complementar(M, L, C):
     matriz_resultato = [linha[:] for linha in M]
```

(no caso o `for` que copia cada linha é usado em uma "list comprehension"). 
Mas esse uso do `for` pode ser complicado em objetos compostos mais complexos (se os elementos das suas matrizes fossem eles mesmos listas, em vez de números, por exemplo, ou se sua matriz fosse um dado passado junto com outros em um dicionário, etc...). 
A solução genérica para isso é a função `deepcopy` no módulo `copy` do Python: ela copia recursivamente cada elemento de um objeto composto, sejam seus sub-elementos listas, dicionários, conjuntos e mesmo instâncias de classes personalizadas.

O seguinte código fica correto, usando `deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def menor_complementar(M,L,C):
    #Onde: M é a matriz principal, L é o número da linha do elemento associado e C o número da coluna do elemento associado
    matriz_resultado = deepcopy(M)
    del(matriz_resultado[L])
    for linha in matriz_resultado:
        del(linha[C])
    return matriz_resultado
```

Comment: Genial jsbueno! Resolveu meu problema. Mto obrigado pela força!!!